# Optimize This Geolocation Update Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query causes some pretty heavy load on the server, and is currently run every 60 seconds.  It finds all rows in a table that do not have lat/long data, and looks up the lat/long based on the city and state, for source and destination locations represented by each row. Right off the bat, I assume that the LTRIM/RTRIM functions are probably slowing things down, and if so, that would be a fairly easy remedy by making sure the data is cleansed on the way in.  But the zip codes/geo database is huge, and even with indexes, things are pretty slow and CPU intensive (entirely possible I'm not creating the indexes properly).  Any advice is welcome - even if the best thing is to somehow limit the number of rows per execution of the query, to spread out the load over time a bit.

---

```
UPDATE
        T1

    SET
            T1.coordinatesChecked   = 1
        ,   T1.FromLatitude         = T2.Latitude
        ,   T1.FromLongitude        = T2.Longitude
        ,   T1.ToLatitude           = T3.Latitude
        ,   T1.ToLongitude          = T3.Longitude

    FROM
        LoadsAvail AS T1
            LEFT JOIN
        ZipCodes AS T2 ON LTRIM(RTRIM(T1.FromCity)) = T2.CityName AND LTRIM(RTRIM(T1.FromState)) = T2.ProvinceAbbr
            LEFT JOIN
        ZipCodes AS T3 ON LTRIM(RTRIM(T1.toCity)) = T3.CityName AND LTRIM(RTRIM(T1.toState)) = T3.ProvinceAbbr

    WHERE
        T1.coordinatesChecked = 0
```

---

Comment: You schema is busted. You should be storing the to and from **zipcode**, and storing geodata (once) on the zipcode

Comment: That's a pretty presumptuous comment. If I had control over the incoming data, I would most certainly try to have it include the zipcode and do the lookup from there. Instead, all we are provided is a city and state for source and destination, hence the task at hand.

Comment: How many cities can there be? This query should perform very well. My guess is there's no index on `ZipCodes(CityName , ProvinceAbbr)` - if you *do* have this index, check datatypes are the same and values are the same (no leading/trailing whitespace etc). Despite your protestations, your schema *is* busted - you have repeated (ie denormalized) data in LoadsAvail. On insert, your app layer should look the cities up and save the geodata as a FK to ZipCodes. If you're one of the unfortunate people that doesn't have an app layer - ie it's an "all DB" server, write a stored proc to do it.

Comment: ZipCodes table is provided from a service. No control over it, and it needs to remain as is because it is auto-updated with new/updated zipcode information on a quarterly basis.  It contains no primary key from this service... it's simply a lookup table with all available zipcodes in the US and Canada, and associated data for each... not only are zipcodes not unique, but of course one city can have many zipcodes.

Comment: The LoadsAvail table has data inserted in bulk every few minutes during peak times. Doing a lookup of source and destination city/state during the insert will have no tangible benefit, and if performance suffers during insert, it will affect the collection of data coming in.

Comment: Call it busted all you want, and go ahead and blame me all you want... this is what i have to work with - an active database with two tables that cannot be modified, and a bulk update task on a schedule that looks at all unhandled records and attempts to get geodata for two cities in each record.  I will check the index again, but in the end i just need a way to limit this query to a set number of records or optimize it in some way that doesn't cause the server to barf during peak times or come up with some new way to handle the entire situation within the boundaries I am forced to honor.

Comment: There is close to 950k zipcode records. Here is the SQL that created the index on that table:

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20170201-164339] ON [dbo].[ZipCodes]
(
 [ProvinceAbbr] ASC,
 [CityName] ASC
)
INCLUDE (  [PostalType],
 [Latitude],
 [Longitude]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF)
GO

Comment: It all seems OK! Typically, how many records have `coordinatesChecked = 0` at any given time? Do you have an index on `coordinatesChecked`? Try defining one and force its use using a hint.

Comment: during peak times, or when the system gets behind, the number of records that need their coordinates checked can be upwards of 1k, though if i can optimize things enough, this should drop.

Comment: Pretty sure i figured out the problem, but not sure how to solve it. Best way to explain is by example:

Comment: If a record has a fromCity/fromState of "Edmonton, Alberta", and the query goes to look up geodata for that city, it finds a total of 25k records (!!) for that city.  That's because there are that many postal codes associated with that city in the database. So this query needs to be changed to use just the FIRST record found, not all 25k.  Same with the toCity and toState. No wonder it was blowing up.